# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, package.json

Source of problem (I think):

```
 "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config config/webpack.config.js"
      },
```

Error log:

```
> somename@1.0.0 dev-server C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\somename
> ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config config/we
bpack.config.js

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! somename@1.0.0 dev-server: `./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpa
ck-dev-server.js --config config/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the somename@1.0.0 dev-server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-29T13_52_01_
170Z-debug.log
```

I am receiving this error and because of that I'm not able to: `npm run dev-server`.

Is there a way to replace `./` part?

Comment: Have you tried replacing all the `/` with \? You are using a windows machine, corrrect?

Comment: @Gab Yes windows. Replace / with what? Ok. Wait.

Comment: NPM runs your script in a cmd window so your path separators are not correct. You need to change those

Comment: I got this error after replacing: 
`npm ERR! Unexpected token w in JSON at position 214 while parsing near '...tch-config config\webpack.config.js"...`
Yeah there's some problem with path separators.

Comment: OK, try doing this: `"dev-server": ".\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js --config config/webpack.config.js"`

Comment: @Gab tried that. Same error again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164097/discussion-between-namo-and-gab).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just refer to the binary directly:

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.config.js"
     },
```

`npm` will run the script in an environment where all the installed packages' binaries (namely `node_modules/.bin/`) are directly available in PATH, including `webpack-dev-server`.

Also using `/` as a path separator is preferable in `package.json` - it works on Windows as well as Linux or OSX.